# Problem with decimal precision in SQL using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have a simple query:

```
var results = from k in db.tree_nodes
              join s in db.stocks
              on k.tree_nodes_id equals s.tree_nodes_id
              into tmpTable
              from rowtmp in tmpTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  stock = (rowtmp.amount == null) ?
                           ((k.code == null) ? (decimal?)null : (decimal?)0)
                           :
                           rowtmp.amount - rowtmp.amount_in_use,
              };
```

This is the generated SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t1].[amount]) IS NULL THEN 
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t0].[code] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),NULL)
                ELSE CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),0)
             END)
        ELSE CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),[t1].[amount] - [t1].[amount_in_use])
     END) AS [stock]
FROM [dbo].[tree_nodes] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[stocks] AS [t1] ON [t0].[tree_nodes_id] = [t1].[tree_nodes_id]
```

The problem is, the generator created `Decimal(33,4)` when converting the results. So I'm getting "*123.4560*" in results instead of "*123.456*" All of my fields in this query are `decimal(14,3)`. I don't mind the *33* part but I need to change the *,4* to *,3*. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could round the decimal values to 3 decimals?

```
var results = from k in db.tree_nodes
              join s in db.stocks
              on k.tree_nodes_id equals s.tree_nodes_id
              into tmpTable
              from rowtmp in tmpTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  stock = (rowtmp.amount == null) ?
                           ((k.code == null) ? (decimal?)null : (decimal?)0)
                           :
                           decimal.Round(rowtmp.amount,3) - decimal.Round(rowtmp.amount_in_use == null ? 0 : rowtmp.amount_in_use,3),
              };
```

Dunno of any way to prevent linq-to-sql from type conversion.